# It's slow to get disconnect signal form BluetoothGatt

Tags: android, callback, disconnect, gatt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I connected to a ble device.

Then I reseted the ble device.

I got a disconnect callback after 8 second at last.

Can I reduce the time to get disconnect callback ?